# correctly specify parameter values when calling a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, default-parameters

I have a function `foo` defined as follows,

```
foo = function(a=1,b=2,c=3){
    console.log("your inputs are a:" +a+", b:"+b + ", c:"+c+".")
}
```

How do I use the default value of `b` and specify `a` and `c` only when calling the function?

For example, I would like to return a console log of `your inputs are a:3, b:2, c:1.` when calling `foo(a=3,c=1)`.

However, by calling `foo(a=3,c=1)`, the console log is `your inputs are a:3, b:1, c:3.`. The JavaScript thinks the `c=1` should be the value of the second parameter `b` and the third parameter `c` is not given and will use its default value of `3`. In addition, by calling this function, the object of `a` and `c` are also created.

Comment: The only thing you can do is leave off parameters at the end of the list; you can't omit a parameter in the middle. *edit* or do the object destructuring as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd pass an object instead, and destructure the arguments:

```js
function foo ({ a=1,b=2,c=3 }){
    console.log("your inputs are a:" +a+", b:"+b + ", c:"+c+".")
}

foo({ a: 99, c: 99 });
```

In case the function may be called without any parameter, assign the default parameter to `{}` too:

```js
function foo ({ a=1,b=2,c=3 } = {}){
    console.log("your inputs are a:" +a+", b:"+b + ", c:"+c+".")
}

foo();
```

You can also explicitly pass `undefined` for missing arguments:

```js
function foo (a=1,b=2,c=3){
    console.log("your inputs are a:" +a+", b:"+b + ", c:"+c+".")
}

foo(99, undefined, 99);
```

Comment: I love your 1st and 2nd way. Interesting how the javascript can capture the unspecified parameter and find its default value. Though I still do not completely understand the mechanisms here. I just wanted to avoid using the 3rd way especially when there are a lot of parameters (with default values) in the function.

Comment: When there are lots of parameters, having multiple *standalone* parameters probably isn't a good idea, because you have to carefully keep in mind which order the parameters are supposed to be in - I'd prefer the object destructuring method regardless, when there are many "parameters", just for the sake of readability, even without the issue of default values.

Comment: Should 'foo(99, undefined, 99);' be 'foo({99, undefined, 99});'?  Or, since you are using all three parameters you don't need the {}?

Comment: When the function accepts multiple standalone parameters, you need to pass `undefined` to fill the "holes" in the parameters. When the function accepts a single object, the (attempted) destructured property will be `undefined` regardless, so specifying the missing parameters is unnecessary (as you can see by pressing "Run code snippet" in the answer)